# Creating a subclass of ArrayList<Item> for inheritance

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

This is for a homework assignment. Basically, the idea is to create a subclass of ArrayList in the Inventory class, meaning the Inventory class will inhert from ArrayList and be able to store instances of the Item class.

So my understanding is that I would create a Inventory class and with ArrayList to connect to the Inventory?

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is just a class and, as with any other (non-final) Java class, you can extend from it by using `extends`:

```
public class Inventory extends ArrayList<Item> {
    //override necessary methods here
}
```

Comment: So from what I am reading from your answer is that i would have to create the arraylist seperate from the inventory class or inside the class you just wrote?

Comment: @user4146749 your question states: *the Inventory class will inhert from ArrayList and be able to store instances of the Item class* since you have to inherit then you will use `extends`. If you have a field `List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();` then you're not extending but using composition.

Comment: sorry if I am asking too much but I am just having a hard time understanding it due to the fast pace of the topic. So like this?

    public class Inventory extends ArrayList<Item>
    List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

Comment: @user4146749 I guess you first define what you really have to do, review the concepts and apply the proper solution. I cannot read your mind, sorry.

Comment: @user4146749 you should not do the both, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I know that if I am trying to extend, meaning this arraylist class will connect to the Inventory class that i would keep them both seperate like an example

Item -> Inventory --> Book --> CD

In other words, both CD and Book will extend to Item?

Comment: @user4146749 that I don't know. I don't know the requirements on your assignment. And using inheritance there is part of your work. Try to keep your questions limited by post, one question at a time.